# Is there a On Map Move event in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, events

In my OpenLayers web app I have registered an `onmousemove` event which performs certain functions.  What I am really after though is a way to register and handle the user panning or zooming the map.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In OpenLayers 2 you can do with the same method:

```
map.events.register(type, obj, listener);
```

> **movestart** triggered after the start of a drag, pan, or zoom
>
> **move** triggered after each drag, pan, or zoom
>
> **moveend** triggered after a drag, pan, or zoom completes
>
> **zoomend** triggered after a zoom completes

example code:

```
 map.events.register("move", map, function() {
            console.log("panning");
        });
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Very odd that `Map` has a `movestart` event, but `Layer` doesn't...

Comment: hi there, seems like this answer is out of date: the current _map_ object has a more standard way to add listeners with _map.addEventListener(evt, handler)_

Answer (score 8):

In OpenLayers 3 you have [*`moveend`*](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapEvent.html#event:moveend), an [`ol.MapEvent`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapEvent.html) triggered by the map itselft. Use it this way:

```
map.on("moveend", function(e){
    // event actions
});
```

This event is triggered in many ways, after [*`click`*](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:click) or [*`dblclick`*](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:dblclick) [`ol.MapBrowserEvent`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html) events.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the automatic Geolocation is enabled, the event is called either the map moved automatically or the user moved it. So, this is a problem.